# Getting ID from entity that hasn't been saved yet

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a scenario where I need to insert a record into a table - the myPerson Entity to get the personID (int identity).  Then I need to take that personID and add it to the familyAdmin.personID.

I was hoping to do all of this in one db.SaveChange();

Is there a way to do it in one since the person entity is part of the userAdmin entity?

**Currently how I have it set up:**

```
userAdmin familyAdmin = new userAdmin();
familyAdmin.signupDate = DateTime.Today;
familyAdmin.lastLogin = DateTime.Today;
familyAdmin.registrationID = newReg.registrationID;

person myPerson = new person();
myPerson.personName = newReg.name;
myPerson.personEmail = newReg.email;
myPerson.personPhone = newReg.phone;
myPerson.personPhoneCarrier = newReg.carrierName;
myPerson.personDOB = newReg.dob;
myPerson.familyID = familyAdmin.familyID;
myPerson.personTypeID = newReg.personTypeID;

familyAdmin.personID = myPerson.personID;
familyAdmin.people.Add(myPerson);

db.userAdmins.Add(familyAdmin);
db.SaveChanges();
```

This option is currently not working.  There is no error that is generated when I do this option.  I just get a 0 instead of a 1,2,3 etc.

The insert into the person table is working and an ID is being generated correctly. It is just when I try to retrieve that ID to do the insert into the UserAdmin table at the same time that I get the 0.

Do I have to do something like this:

```
person myPerson = new person();
myPerson.personName = newReg.name;
myPerson.personEmail = newReg.email;
myPerson.personPhone = newReg.phone;
myPerson.personPhoneCarrier = newReg.carrierName;
myPerson.personDOB = newReg.dob;
myPerson.familyID = familyAdmin.familyID;
myPerson.personTypeID = newReg.personTypeID;

db.person.Add(myPerson);
db.SaveChanges();


userAdmin familyAdmin = new userAdmin();
familyAdmin.signupDate = DateTime.Today;
familyAdmin.lastLogin = DateTime.Today;
familyAdmin.registrationID = newReg.registrationID;
familyAdmin.personID = myPerson.personID;

db.userAdmins.Add(familyAdmin);
db.SaveChanges();
```

**Partial EDMX image:**

[image]

Comment: And is option one not working for you?

Comment: yes that is correct. - I updated my question to reflect that.

Comment: What it said when it not working? The error message?

Comment: If you have navigation properties set up correct, you should be able to do everything in one call by assining myPerson to `familyAdmin.Person = myPerson;` or something along those lines.

Comment: @CodeNotFound - I updated my question.  No error, I just get an 0 instead of a 1,2,3 (since it is the Identity to the table).  However the insert into the person table is working and an ID is being generated correctly. It is just when I try to retrieve that ID to do the insert into the UserAdmin table at the same time.

Comment: Use familyAdmin.Person = myPerson

Comment: @ErikEJ - I can do this: myPerson.userAdmin = familyAdmin; but not the other way around.  I don't seem to have a Person in familyAdmin

Comment: Can you show us the configuration you write between those two entites? The OnModelCreating method?

Comment: @CodeNotFound - I'll be honest I don't know what that means.  I probably didn't use that method.

Answer (score 3):

The first option is not working because of these two lines:

```
myPerson.familyID = familyAdmin.familyID;

familyAdmin.personID = myPerson.personID;
```

Those lines are not necessary because you're checking identifiers that are not created in the database.

Your code should look like this:

```
userAdmin familyAdmin = new userAdmin();
familyAdmin.signupDate = DateTime.Today;
familyAdmin.lastLogin = DateTime.Today;
familyAdmin.registrationID = newReg.registrationID;

person myPerson = new person();
myPerson.personName = newReg.name;
myPerson.personEmail = newReg.email;
myPerson.personPhone = newReg.phone;
myPerson.personPhoneCarrier = newReg.carrierName;
myPerson.personDOB = newReg.dob;
// myPerson.familyID = familyAdmin.familyID; Not necessary
myPerson.personTypeID = newReg.personTypeID;

// familyAdmin.personID = myPerson.personID; Not necessary
familyAdmin.people.Add(myPerson);

db.userAdmins.Add(familyAdmin);
db.SaveChanges();
```

If you have correctly configured the relation between `people` property on `userAdmin` entity and `person` entity so by using `familyAdmin.people.Add(myPerson);` and `calling db.SaveChanges();` then EF will call `DetectChanges` internally so that will fix the relationship between those two entities and generate the correct SQL in the correct order because it knows which entity need to be inserted first and which entity need the foreign key id.

Comment: I will give that a shot.  Thanks -

Comment: I was able to get the familyID into the person entity, but personID was still 0 in the userAdmin entity.   Any ideas?